# How do I add the "crossorigin" tag to a dynamically loaded script?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp, cors

Context: [To quote the Mozilla documentation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

> Normal script tags will pass minimal information to the window.onerror
>   for scripts which do not pass the standard CORS checks. To allow error
>   logging for sites which use a separate domain for static media,
>   several browsers have enabled the crossorigin attribute for scripts
>   using the same definition as the standard img crossorigin attribute.

We realized our scripts were suffering from this issue ever since we moved our javascript to a CDN. We added the `crossorigin` attribute to our script tags, which works fine for the "hardcoded" script tags, but we load some scripts dynamically, and I can't figure out how to add the `crossorigin` tag to these scripts.

In Chrome 40:
If I add a script tag dynamically using Javascript, like so:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.charset = 'utf-8';
script.crossorigin = 'anonymous';
script.src = some_url_on_another_domain;
head.appendChild(script);
```

I would expect for the crossorigin tag to get added to the script tag that gets inserted into my document. However, when I examine the script tag in Developer tools, it is clearly not there. (And I can verify that the `origin` header is not being set in the request headers when requesting the script.)

For now, I am falling back to using ajax requests for these cross domain scripts instead, so there are workarounds, but now I am curious if it's possible to add the crossorigin tag on dynamic script tags.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Well, I discovered my problem.

This:

```
script.crossorigin = 'anonymous';
```

should be this:

```
script.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
```

**Note the capital "O"**. That attribute isn't capitalized in the HTML, but is capitalized in the JS interface. Good to know!

Embarrassing, but I've decided to immortalize my mistake rather than delete the question in case someone else makes the same one.

Comment: also both `script.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');` and `script.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');` works

Comment: Great find! Stupid case-sensitive javascript.

Comment: I was caught by this trap as well. I should have referred to [HTMLScriptElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#properties)'s doc instead of [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attributes)'s.

Comment: @Sanya_Zol the lowercase `o` does not work. Inspect the link element in the DOM tree, and when the code uses lowercase, the `crossOrigin` attribute will be `null`. (At least in Chrome.)

Comment: @Karl I checked in latest firefox and non-latest chromium, and with `script.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');` browser sets the attribute in DOM as well as adds cors headers (`set-fetch-*`) in network tab.